# Molar specific heat constant for polyatomic gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

My copy of "Resnick and Halliday" states that

> "$Cv$=$(f/2)R$ which agrees with the experimental evidence for diatomic gases($f$=5), but **it is too low for polyatomic gases($f=6$).**

Exactly what do they mean by the statement that I have highlighted in bold? What's **too low**? $Cv$? How come? Doesn't $Cv$ vary *directly* with $f$?

Please share your insights and help. MUCH thanks in advance :) Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It means that equation underestimates the experimental $C_v$ value for polyatomic gases. Indeed, the experimental $C_v$ value is about 15% larger than what is given by that equation ([source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/kinetic/shegas.html#c5)).

This is because polyatomic gases have other vibrational degrees of freedom that must be included.